# Rational connectedness of a submanifold of a Fano manifold

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a Fano manifold of Picard number one.A component $K$ of rational curves in $X$ is called a minimal rational component if the evaluation map $\mathbb{P}^1 \times K \to X$ is dominant and the degree of the curves in $K$ is minimal with this property. Let $C$ be a smooth projective curve in $X$ such that $K_x$, the variety of minimal rational curve passing through $x$ is complete and irreducible for all $x \in C$. Then $K_C:= \bigcup_{x \in C}K_x$ is a complete subvariety of $K$. Let $X_C$ be the image of $\mathbb{P}^1 \times K_C$ under the evaluation map. Note that for a general point $x \in C$, the image of $\mathbb{P}^1 \times K_x$ is a divisor in $X_C$.

Question: Can any two points in $X_C$ be joined by a chain of rational curves belonging to $K_C$ ? In other words, is $X_C$ a rc-$K_C$ manifold?

Comment: That is not true without further hypotheses.  Are you assuming that the genus of $C$ equals $0$?  Even so, typically the variety $K_x$ is not rationally connected (this is related to the "sign" of the second graded piece of the Chern character of $X$, not just positivity of the first Chern class of $X$).  The image of $X_C$ may be singular, and that can actually make it easier to find chains of rational curves.  However, often the morphism from $K_C$ to $X_C$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: I am not assuming anything about genus of $C. K_x$ even need not be uniruled. But the image of $\mathbb{P}^1 \times K_x$ is rationally connected, as every point in the image is connected to $x$ by a rational curve. But I am not sure about $X_C$. Clearly $C \subset X_C$, which is just image of $\{0\} \times K_C$ under the evaluation map.  It is enough to show that given any two points in $C$, there is chain of rational curves in $X_C$ connecting them. I am not sure how to do that.  In the last comment you said $K_C$ is isomorphic to $X_C$. I dont see any natural map from $K_C \to X_C$.

Comment: Just a point of notation: what you call “rationally connected” is called “rationally chain connected” by many.

Comment: There is no reason, a priori, that a general pair of points of $C$ would be connected by a chain of minimal rational curves, each of which happens to also intersect $C$.  It can happen, e.g., for projective spaces or quadric hypersurfaces.  However, typically it will not happen.

Comment: Definitely any two points in $C$ can be connected by chain of minimal rational curves in $X$ but all minimal rational curves in such a chain need not be contained in $X_C$. Here minimal rational curves means curves in a minimal dominating family.

Comment: Basically you and I just wrote the same comment to one another.  There is no reason that $X_C$ should be rationally chain connected.

Comment: For each $x \in C$, the image of $\mathbb{P}^1 \times K_x$ is a divisor in $X_C$. I was wondering if two such effective divisors intersects, or somehow if we can say such a divisor is ample.

Comment: There is no reason for those divisors to intersect.